# Dual monitors with one above the other?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome

I'm using Gnome 3 and proprietary Nvidia drivers. I have tried to set in nvidia-settings my external monitor to be "above" my main one (it's a laptop). However, when I try to drag a window up from the main display to the external one, it gets stuck and can't move past a certain point. Trying to maximize it changes its decoration so it looks maximized (i.e. no borders, etc), but its size or position doesn't change.

Now, if I set my external monitor to be "to the left" of the main one, it works, which is why I'm suspecting this is a Gnome issue, not an Nvidia one.

Anyone know how to fix this?

**Update:** some versions:

- Gnome: 3.2.2.1
- Nvidia: 280.13

**Update 2:** I can see that Gnome 3.4 is out, and among the [release notes](http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.4/) is better external monitor support. However, they only mention a small fix that is unrelated to my problem. Can anyone with Gnome 3.4 and access to an external monitor please test this out and tell me if it works? I don't want to go through the hassle of upgrading my Ubuntu installation unless I know for certain it's going to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you checked `nvidia-settings` ?

Comment: Yes, that's how I set up the monitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will conclude that this is a Gnome bug (which I have [filed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677089)), since this works in Unity. Also, I have tried using the open source nouveau drivers (which properly support xrandr), and the same thing happens.

Comment: Have there been any update on this bug? It's still present in Cinnamon, Gala and all the other mutter based managers. ( Using mint 14. )

Comment: Well, [the bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663690) is still open, I guess you can read the comments on it for updates.

Answer (score 2):

have a similar setup and therefore issue here but:
if I get to get the external (upper) monitor as main one with the top panel than everything works fine. The downside is the process how to get the upper monitor to be the main one. For me, it takes a couple of active/deactive apply reapply... actions in nvidia-settings tool. Have not found any determinism on that one.

also to mention, at work I have Intel hardware and multimonitor-support works without issues.

thus it might be a gnome issue with how nvidia does its multimonitor-support?

Comment: I also achieved this by first deactivating my lower (built-in) display and then reactivating it again from "Displays" window.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for it... disable sticky edges in **displays** settings

Comment: On version 280.13???